# Elasticsearch Root mapping unsupported param

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, logstash

I am trying to configure an index in elastic search with the PUT commands as below and getting the error as following. I'm not able to figure out what's the error. I'm using 7.4.2 version for ELK

The PUT code is as below:

```
PUT /myfeed
{
   "settings": {
      "index": {
         "number_of_shards": 1,
         "number_of_replicas": 0
      },
      "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
            "folding": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "standard",
               "char_filter": ["html_strip"],
               "filter": ["lowercase", "asciifolding"]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "feed": {
         "_all": {
            "enabled": false
         },
         "properties": {
            "feed": {
               "type": "keyword"
            },
            "link": {
               "type": "keyword"
            },
            "published": {
               "type": "date"
            },
            "message": {
               "type": "string",
               "analyzer": "folding"
            },
            "title": {
               "type": "string",
               "analyzer": "folding"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**the error on the console is as below:**

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [feed : {_all={enabled=false}, properties={feed={type=keyword}, link={type=keyword}, published={type=date}, message={analyzer=folding, type=string}, title={analyzer=folding, type=string}}}]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [feed : {_all={enabled=false}, properties={feed={type=keyword}, link={type=keyword}, published={type=date}, message={analyzer=folding, type=string}, title={analyzer=folding, type=string}}}]",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [feed : {_all={enabled=false}, properties={feed={type=keyword}, link={type=keyword}, published={type=date}, message={analyzer=folding, type=string}, title={analyzer=folding, type=string}}}]"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Please help me fixing this

Comment: _all is deprecated from 6.x and string from 5.x

Comment: Yeah got it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

_all is deprecated as told by Lupanoide(thanks)
So The mapping that worked for me as below

```
 PUT /myfeed
{
  "mappings": {
         "properties": {
            "feed": {
               "type": "keyword"
            },
            "link": {
               "type": "keyword"
            },
            "published": {
               "type": "date"
            },
            "message": {
               "type": "text",
               "analyzer": "folding"
            },
            "title": {
               "type": "keyword"
            }
         }
      },
   "settings": {
      "index": {
         "number_of_shards": 1,
         "number_of_replicas": 0
      },
      "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
            "folding": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "standard",
               "char_filter": ["html_strip"],
               "filter": ["lowercase", "asciifolding"]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Thanks